# Android dynamic module only on arm processors

Tags: android, android-ndk, dynamic-delivery

I'm adding dynamic feature to my application.

In dynamic module I have dependency with external library, which supports only arm abis.

My app supports arm and x86 abis. 
Additionally I have a few of native code in app module. I'm using cmake for it. Part of my app gradle file:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

When I try to build my bundle

```
./gradlew bundleDebug
```

I'm getting error

> Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebugBundle'.
>    1 exception was raised by workers:
>     com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.ValidationException: All modules with native libraries must support the same set of ABIs, but module 'dynamic_module' supports '[ARM64_V8A, ARMEABI_V7A]' and module 'base' supports '[ARM64_V8A, ARMEABI_V7A, X86, X86_64]'.

Can I add my dynamic module only for arm processors by any entry in gradle? Or if not, any idea what I should to do?

Comment: As the error messages says, you are supposed build or provide all libraries for every ABI that you want to support. I suppose you could do something like putting this particular library in the `assets` folder, and at runtime copy it to somewhere in your app's private filesystem area and load it with `System.load`. It will be a bit more work, and you obviously need to think about how to handle the case where the library isn't available.

Comment: The better way for me was modify external library and add there directories for x86 processors with empty .so files